# How to prevent `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/` for electron-react app

Tags: reactjs, electron, upgrade, navigateurl

Typescript just relase 3.7.3 with optional chaining, so I wanted to upgrade a [project](https://github.com/JiahuaZhang/electron-react) for this feature.

However, after runing `yarn upgrade --latest`, and doing `yarn start`, the app will reload infinitely.

After couple days of debugging. This is what I find out, it seems like if anything changed recently on `/public` folder, then the app will be `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/` which will cause it to reload infinitely due to the design of my app.

The project was working for previous dependencies, so I am not sure whethere it's a `react` or `electron` upgrade that they changed it such that the app will watch for `/public` folder. When `public` folder changed, and causing the app to navigate to `localhost:3000`. Anyone know what's the cause of this phenomena? And the reason behind this change, and also how to pass around this?

By the way, my app was a simple epub reader application. Currently, my app will load all the images, css files and stored them to `public` folder (delete those files on unmount). Thus the app can load these images, stylesheets. (I just tried to store these files just inside the `src` folder, and it seems react won't be able to load these resources dynamically).

Comment: It seems like this pull request [Enable page reloading for files in `public/`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1546/files) enabled react to reload application when it detects folder changed on `public` folder. To deliberately cancel this settting, changed [it](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L62), to `watchContentBase: false`. Of course, this is not the recommended way doing so when it comes to change library file itself. I wish `react-scripts start` could give us more control of it (--options).